Blue Prism VB Code Stage - End of statement expected Error
Inputs and Outputs here
Here is the code below for the error above and i have added the inputs/outputs.  Am i missing something silly? Ive tried running this a few times and taking the brackets out here ("SelectedNumbers") as blue prism was giving me an error for this also, so when i added the brackets i get the end of statement expected error.
' Initialize variables
Dim NegativeNumber, PositiveCollection, SelectedNumbers
NegativeNumber = GetStageVariable("NegativeNumber")
PositiveCollection = GetStageVariable("PositiveCollection")
SelectedNumbers = ""

' Sort PositiveCollection in ascending order
' Assuming PositiveCollection is already sorted

' Loop through PositiveCollection
For Each num in PositiveCollection
    ' Calculate sum
    sum = NegativeNumber + num
    
    ' Check if sum >= 0
    If sum >= 0 Then
        ' Add num to SelectedNumbers
        SelectedNumbers = SelectedNumbers & num & ","
        
        ' Update NegativeNumber
        NegativeNumber = NegativeNumber - num
        
        ' Check end condition
        If NegativeNumber >= 0 Then Exit For
    End If
Next

' Output SelectedNumbers
SetStageVariable("SelectedNumbers"), SelectedNumbers


That last line is not valid VB.NET syntax. What exactly are you expecting that to do?

If you have a list of numbers and you want to create a comma-delimited String from it then use String.Join(",", myList).

Are you sure the last line shouldn't be SetStageVariable("SelectedNumbers", SelectedNumbers)?
